# Replacing hex color code in string to colored html tag

Tags: javascript, regex

Given a string that includes color codes, i want to match the codes and replace them with a `<span style='color: code'>` with the same color code to result in a colored HTML string.

this is what i already tried:

```js
function parseColors(str) {
  let reg = /#[0-9a-f]{6}/gi
  let arr = str.match(reg)
  if (arr) {
    arr.forEach(m => {
      str = str.replace(m, `<span style='color: ${m}'>`)
      str += "</span>"
    })
  }
  return str
}

console.log(parseColors(
  "#abcdefthe, #ff0000 red #abcdef fox"
))
// prints:
// <span style='color: <span style='color: #abcdef'>'>the, <span style='color: #ff0000'> red #abcdef fox</span></span></span>
```

the problem is, it replaces the same color twice, so first #abcdef would be a `<span>` tag, but then it replaces the color in the tag with another `<span>`

Comment: Is your RegEx matching twice, or is the code iterating twice? In other words, what does `arr` look like?

Comment: (1) You are appending `"</span>"` to the *whole* string instead of inserting it after the match. (2) (Better.) The `match` has another property: [`index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) which tells you the location of the match. You could use that to build another string with the replacements in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the greatest solution, but it handles adding the end tag appropriately.

```js
const HexPattern = /(#[0-9a-f]{6})(\s*[\w,]+\s*)/gi

function parseColors(str) {
  return str.replace(HexPattern, (s, g0, g1) => `<span style="color:${g0}">${g1}</span>`)
}

let html = parseColors("#abcdefthe, #ff0000 red #abcdef fox")

console.log(html)
document.body.innerHTML = html
```